# Tools for quantifier elimination in linear integer arithmetic

Tags: z3, quantifiers

Are there any other available (and still supported) SMT tools that perform quantifier elimination for linear integer arithmetic besides Z3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Princess](http://www.philipp.ruemmer.org/princess.shtml), by Philipp Rümmer. It supports quantifier-elimination and is actively maintained.